# how to make google translate to show original language names

Tags: google-translate

I added google translate to my web page but I couldn't figure out how to show language texts in their own language. For example: English, Español, Français, Português, Deutsch, Русский, Italiano, العربية, 中文..

I see all the language texts in English.

```
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement(
        {
          pageLanguage: 'en', 
          layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, 
          multilanguagePage: true}, 
        'google_translate_element');
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
          src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">

  </script>
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm looking for the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

just add a class where the name is included like so:

```html
<h3 class="notranslate">NAME DONT CHANGE WITH TRANSLATION</h3>
```